# Mysql update query with IF statement

Tags: mysql

I'm learning to use mysql so i created a really simple project manager program.
i wanted to track if a user saw her/his tasks in a project. So i want to update user_seen_task filed when a project is got queried by a user, but obviously i only want to update this field if it isn't already set.

This is my approach what i have already:

```
UPDATE task 
SET user_seen_task = 1, user_seen_task_date = NOW() 
WHERE project_id = 14 AND user = 4 AND user_seen_job != 1
```

Unfortunately this query will update user_seen_task_date every time it runs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE task 
SET user_seen_task = 1
    , user_seen_task_date = CASE 
                               WHEN  user_seen_task_date IS NULL THEN NOW() 
                               ELSE user_seen_task_date 
                            END 
WHERE project_id = 14 
AND user = 4 
AND user_seen_job != 1
```

Or if it doesn't need to update user_seen_task in this case, just add

```
AND user_seen_task_date IS NULL
```

into your where clause

```
UPDATE task 
     SET user_seen_task = 1, user_seen_task_date = NOW() 
WHERE project_id = 14 AND user = 4 AND user_seen_job != 1
AND user_seen_task_date IS NULL
```